# How to determine whether the control is within the display area

Tags: ios, uilabel

How do I determine whether the control is within the display area in iOS?

e.g.

There is a `UILabel`, it will slide to the left from the right side of the screen until it slides off the screen to the left of the border, how do I determine if it has slipped out of the border of it?

---

I use the animation block model. When the animation is completion, we can be sure the Label has exceeded 0;

Now I want delete the Label.

e.g.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.5
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^
 {

     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];

     CGRect lsframe = labelShow.frame;
     lsframe.origin.x = 0;
     lsframe.origin.y = dphv.mImgContent.frame.origin.y;
     lsframe.size.width = 8;
     lsframe.size.height = imgH;


     CGRect frame = labelShow.frame;
     frame.origin.x = 600;
     labelShow.frame = frame;

     frame = labelShow.frame;
     frame.origin.x = -180;
     labelShow.frame = frame;

 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     NSLog(@"animation finished");

     labelShow = nil; //but this line has error, how can I do this;
 }];
```

I use this example, but this example has a very serious problem, cause memory up, even more than 100M, but I do not know how to fix reform. This is the URL: https://github.com/yinkou/OBaconView

Answer (score 1):

The label has a `frame` property which lets you know where it is within its superview. The superview has a `bounds` property that lets you know where the content can be. Using these properties, you can check if the label's frame is within the superview's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the frame.origin.x param for the label as its moving. Assuming the parent view's x param is aligned with the screen's x= 0,  wehn the label's x becomes less than 0, your label is out of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the method `-convertRect:toView:` to find where the view falls into the view controller's view. Use the rect that is returned from the method, check to see if any of the corners fall within the main view.